# C# cast exception in C# dll

Tags: c#, object, indexing, casting, overloading

I have a class with a field which is assigned to array of type T or a dll object of type T which has overload for `this [int i]` to imitate an array (it uses unmanaged memory and accesses that using overload)

```
    public T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return ((T[])array)[i]; // can't use return array[i] directly
        }
        set { }
    }
```

when I use dll object, it throws cast exception. I supposed that `(T[])` would trigger the overload `[]` of the object instead of casting to `float[]` but it always casts to `float[]` and object type is `FloatArr` which has `public float  this[int i]`.

Is there a way to treat primitive arrays as a cast meanwhile treating other custom types as an overload trigger?

If this is not possible, how to return type `T` while returned type such as `float` can be gathered from a simple float array or some custom type with overload to return float? I don't want to add float,int,byte,double,char,... one by one. I need type `T` work for all whether the object field is a C# array or a custom type with overloaded indexer?

What I need actually:

```
    // developer supplies here with his/hers own array
    // or this library uses its own fast C++ wrapper with a [] overload
    public object array { get; set; }

    // returns float, int, byte
    public T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return array[i]; // float[], int[], FloatArr[], ...
        }
        set { }
    }
```

**Edit:** if this is a bad design pattern please tell me. I need this class to treat a property same whether it is a C# array or a C++ wrapper C# dll object with `[]` overload.

**Edit-2:** Here is the usage in my mind:

```
MyArr<float> gpu = new MyArr<float>(1024);
gpu.array=new float[1024];
gpu[35]=40;

or


MyArr<float> gpu = new MyArr<float>(1024);
gpu.allocateUnManagedToArray(); // now array field is a custom object
gpu[35]=40;
```

**Edit-3:** here is the custom class that I put into array field:

```
public class FloatArr
{
    public float this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            unsafe
            {
                float* p = (float*)hArr.ToPointer();
                return *(p + i);
            }

        }
        set {
            unsafe
            {
                float* p = (float*)hArr.ToPointer();
                *(p + i) = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit-4:** Just incase I'm not clear:

- I have a class with a `[]` overload to work as an array
- But it also has a field that sometimes given another class which overloads `[]` too!
- Now I just need other developers, to be able to supply their own C# arrays, when they don't want this class' own C++ wrapper object.
- Then in both cases, I need it `[]` indexable from same field (a float array or a C++ wrapper with `[]` overload).

Ofcourse I can write all conditions for float int byte all one by one but then it would take much longer. Generic class is easy and it should be easy but I'm missing something here which I can't see. When I add struct arrays, code will grow even more in future so I need generic class helplessly.

Comment: I don't understand... why isn't it `public T[] array { get; set; }` ?

Comment: it can be unmanaged memory wrapper too(as C++ allocator and accesser)

Comment: what is `it`?  `T` or  `T[]`  Since T is generic, I don't know why T couldn't be anything (managed or unmanaged).

Comment: For example, this class will put its own C++ wrapper there and get-set float values in there. Or, developer will supply his/hers own C# float array then this class will use it instead.

Comment: @ErikPhilips can I assign FloatArr typed object into a T[] field ?

Comment: Why would `T[]` *not* cast to an array? That's exactly what you're telling it to do. Perhaps you actually want to cast to `IList<T>` and then use the indexer that provides? A [mcve] would really help here...

Comment: @JonSkeet it casts, but not when I have given it a custom wrapper class before

Comment: You need to show a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that uses a custom wrapper class. Your current examples are not helpful in explaining why your custom wrapper won't cast because none of your examples use a valid custom wrapper where you included the definition of the wrapper. Your new Edit2 does not contain this information either, we need to see the code for `allocateUnManagedToArray()` and we need to see the full definition of the class that `allocateUnManagedToArray()` assigns to `array` internally.

Comment: Okay, I added edit2 as a usage case I needed

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment at all, in terms of "but not when I have given it a custom wrapper class before"

Comment: @JonSkeet If the field is given a wrapper instance, it gives cast error because I noobly thought that it would use operator overload instead of cast. If the field is given an array instance, it works. But implementing IList on the wrapper solved the problem.

Comment: My question is really why you thought it would use the operator, when `(T[])` is a *cast* operator. You're specifically asking to cast to `T[]`, so that's what it did.

Comment: @JonSkeet I wasn't aware of IList, and also thought it could somehow enable listing/indexing capabilities when types are not compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is not use arrays but instead use the [`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface. You then need to make your custom class implement that interface.

```
class FloatArr : IList<float>
{
    //(snip)
    // p and hArr's decliration and assignment
    //(snip)

    public float this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            unsafe
            {
                float* p = (float*)hArr.ToPointer();
                return *(p + i);
            }

        }
        set
        {
            unsafe
            {
                float* p = (float*)hArr.ToPointer();
                *(p + i) = value;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator<float> IEnumerable<float>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void ICollection<float>.Add(float item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void ICollection<float>.Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool ICollection<float>.Contains(float item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void ICollection<float>.CopyTo(float[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool ICollection<float>.Remove(float item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int ICollection<float>.Count
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    bool ICollection<float>.IsReadOnly
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    int IList<float>.IndexOf(float item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IList<float>.Insert(int index, float item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IList<float>.RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If you don't need to write to the array and only read you can greatly simplfy the class by using [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
class FloatArr : IReadOnlyList<float>
{
    //(snip)
    // p and hArr's decliration and assignment
    //(snip)

    public float this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            unsafe
            {
                float* p = (float*)hArr.ToPointer();
                return *(p + i);
            }

        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator<float> IEnumerable<float>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int IReadOnlyCollection<float>.Count
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

Then your container class is changed to

```
// developer supplies here with his/hers own array
// or this library uses its own fast C++ wrapper with a [] overload
public IList<T> array { get; set; }

// returns float, int, byte
public T this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        return array[i]; // float[], int[], FloatArr, ...
    }
    set
    {
        array[i] = value;
    }
}
```

or

```
// developer supplies here with his/hers own array
// or this library uses its own fast C++ wrapper with a [] overload
public IReadOnlyList<T> array { get; set; }

// returns float, int, byte
public T this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        return array[i]; // float[], int[], FloatArr, ...
    }
}
```

Comment: So with an interface, these will be compatible. Then I will need to make any future structure types implement IList?

Comment: There are 3 possible interfaces to choose from `IList`, `IList<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>`, any one will work, the built in `Array` type in .net implements all 3 interfaces. You only need to just pick one and make your classes that will be used as the backing store implement that interface.

Comment: I feel I'm still noob of programming in oop. Is this a bad design or not?

Comment: I also posted a 2nd answer that is simpler to code but will be much slower than using a interface. If you have the option you should use the Interfaces instead of `dynamic`. Edit: Using interfaces is not a bad design at all. The entire point of them is so you don't need to do the casts to get the features you want.

Answer (score 1):

Another option instead of implementing `IList<T>` or `IReadOnlyList<T>` you could use the [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) keyword to do runtime binding instead of compile time binding. However this will have much worse performance than using `IList<T>` or `IReadOnlyList<T>`

```
// developer supplies here with his/hers own array
// or this library uses its own fast C++ wrapper with a [] overload
public dynamic array { get; set; }

// returns float, int, byte
public T this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        return array[i]; // float[], int[], FloatArr[], ...
    }
    set 
    {
        array[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need my library 3.5 (or 2.0  at times) compatible. So dynamic may not be good for me?

Comment: Using interfaces would be much better to do then.

Comment: Thank you very much(Jon Skeet said it earlier but I didn't understand at that time)